# PHP/ curl/file_get_contents. Security and file size and type verification when getting remote files

Tags: php, security, curl, file-get-contents

I want to enable users to copy or download images from a remote url or upload files (that may include pdfs and txt files etc. ) from their computer.  To do this, I have experimented with file_get_contents and curl both of which my host supports.  For the local uploads, I am just using php.  They do the basic job of transferring the data.  However, I am trying to find the best way to validate the contents of the file to avoid propagation of malicious code or loading up my server with excessively large files.

In many cases, the file will be dynamically generated and therefore not end in a known extension so checking file extensions is not an option, besides lacking security.

Using the mime type from the headers is one option and I have code to do that.

```
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);  // object oriented approach!
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));  // e.g. gives "image/jpeg"

switch($mime_type) {
    case "image/jpeg":
        // your actions go here...
}
```

However, it is evidently not too hard to spoof mime type.

A few posts suggest sniffing out the magic numbers at the beginning of files but these too can be spoofed.

For the limited case of images, one can use

```
$imginfo_array = getimagesize($tempFile);
```

As far as I know, this does not work for pdfs, docs etc.

Even taken together these methods do not seem very robust.  Yet numerous sites routinely allow you to upload, pin or otherwise get remote files and have somehow managed security issues.

Would appreciate suggestions on best security and verification practices-as in curl vs. file_get_contents vs. wd--as well as other libraries or other techniques for obtaining file size and file type before transferring to my server.

Note: I want to allow transfers of mainstream image formats such as .jpg and .gif and uploads of pdf files, doc and docx files, xls files, and similar common formats.

Thanks in advance for recommendations and advice.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am trying to find the best way to validate the contents of the file to avoid propagation of malicious code

[File uploading](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software#secure-php-files) is one of the attack surfaces I want to eliminate in the PHP ecosystem. Whether you're downloading files with cURL or allowing users to submit them from a web form, the solution doesn't change much.

To resolve remote code execution: Upload your files to a non-publicly-accessible folder outside your web root, then serve them with a proxy script (hint: `readfile()` or `file_get_contents()`) instead of allowing direct access.

Then even if there's malicious code, Apache/nginx will not think to execute it.

> ... or loading up my server with excessively large files

If you're using cURL, [this is easily done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17642638/2224584).