# How to set a maximum size limit to PHP cURL downloads?

Tags: php, curl

Is there a maximum size limit to PHP cURL downloads? ie. will cURL  quit when transfer reaches a certain file limit?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

It's for a site that downloads remote images. I want to ensure that cURL will stop when it reaches a certain limit.

Also my research shows `getimagesize()` downloads the image, to return its size so its not an option.

Comment: Are you trying to get the image size in bytes or its dimensions?, curl will still download the file first.

Comment: i wanted to know whether there is a maximum limit imposed default by curl. don't want to choke up the disk, if a download goes rogue.and whether it is changeable, like through php.ini

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*I have another answer that addresses the situation even better to leave here for posterity.*

`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is good for this but **`CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` is the best**.

```
// We need progress updates to break the connection mid-way
curl_setopt($cURL_Handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128); // more progress info
curl_setopt($cURL_Handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($cURL_Handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function(
    $DownloadSize, $Downloaded, $UploadSize, $Uploaded
){
    // If $Downloaded exceeds 1KB, returning non-0 breaks the connection!
    return ($Downloaded > (1 * 1024)) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Keep in mind that even if the [**PHP.net states**^](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`:

> A callback accepting **five parameters**.

My local tests have featured only **four (4) parameters** as the *1st (handle)* is not present.

Comment: went through the php.net page and found the similar code to  this.  just adding up 

`// Small buffer more progress info/callbacks
curl_setopt($this->_Handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);`

Comment: @SojanVJose Right! For what you need, this is the best approach. Added the option you mentioned in the sample code here.

Comment: tested it with various file and works fine. switching this to the answer as, this code is more useful ..

Comment: In my case, the callback really had **five (5) parameters**. This is only to say, that one has to be careful and test the function for themselves.

Comment: In my case returning nonzero from callback cause empty download result.
curl_error says: "Callback aborted".
So i cannot get limited part of requesting page this way.

Comment: hmm.. for some reason when I say $myVar = curl_exec($cURL_Handle) ... it echos it in the browser?  Also, I had to use 5 vars to get this to work, as said in the docs

Comment: Variable $Downloaded not correctly reports downloaded content size. I was only able to extract approximately good measure of page total bytes downloaded with expression `memory_get_usage() - $memory_used_before_curl_exec` inside a progress function.

Comment: To add a error message: `if (CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK === curl_errno(curl_errno)) echo 'File is to big';

Answer (score 6):

The server does not honor the Range header. The best you can do is to cancel the connection as soon as you receive more data than you want. Example:

```
<?php
$curl_url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/edgen?xml=1';
$curl_handle = curl_init($curl_url);

$data_string = "";
function write_function($handle, $data) {
global $data_string;
$data_string .= $data;
if (strlen($data_string) > 1000) {
    return 0;
}
else
    return strlen($data);
} 

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_function');

curl_exec($curl_handle);

echo $data_string;
```

Perhaps more cleanly, you could use the http wrapper (this would also use curl if it was compiled with --with-curlwrappers). Basically you would call fread in a loop and then fclose on the stream when you got more data than you wanted. You could also use a transport stream (open the stream with fsockopen, instead of fopen and send the headers manually) if allow_url_fopen is disabled.

Comment: what i wanted to know was whether there is something that controlls globally, every php curl downloads from server. something like upload_max_filesize . codeangry answers that. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

***There is.** It's the PHP memory limit, I presume. As the download is done in memory...*

**But [`CURLOPT_FILE` and `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER`^](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) are your friends as they allow you to reroute the `cURL` download to streams.** This allows you to create `tmpfile()` temporary streams *(`stream_get_meta_data()` gives you the file path)* and download to them. And downloading directly to drive lifts the memory limitations.

Once the download completes, you get to read those files and do what you wish with them.

Comment: though what i want to do is just the reverse, the php memory limit answers my original question. i want to put a limit to the maximum download size of curl requests on my server for safety. 
was hoping for something similar to upload_max_filesize exclusive to curl.

Comment: @SojanVJose Use @DrZIZO's suggestion with the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. But make sure the limit you need to set is not too large. There's no option to do this but can be done if you use the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and keep appending to a buffer until a limit is reached.

Comment: went in with @drzizo's code. seemed easier to implement and also this scenario deals with  limits that are not too large .

Comment: @SojanVJose Posted a new answer. It's an even more suitable solution. Make sure you test it as there are some discrepancies between documentation and real-life use.