# how to avoid/stop this type of page in php curl

Tags: php, curl

i am using following function to use download pages for my analysis it works perfect

```
function gdll($target_url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
$html= curl_exec($ch);

if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}
return $html;
}

echo $data=gdll($url);
```

as i said it work perfect on any type of url but now i trouble in due this type link

```
http://www.woo55.com/play/6129/14-black-eyed-peas-audio-delite-at-low-fidelity-%28www-songslover-com%29-mp3
```

caution : if you open this url  it will hang up your browser and generate

```
Warning: opendir(/home/woo55555/public_html/adata/6129) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/woo55555/public_html/play.php on line 71

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/woo55555/public_html/play.php on line 72

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/woo55555/public_html/play.php on line 72

Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/woo55555/public_html/play.php on line 72
```

and continue generate lines so it is infinite

Now my question is how i can avoid this type of URL any method that i can able to check this page have problem my code ignore then continue on next link

Comment: Maybe limit the download size, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641073/how-to-set-a-maximum-size-limit-to-php-curl-downloads

Comment: Is the problem that the file does not exist or is that is is a certain type of file?

Comment: well above comments give me idea i will very happy if i get rock solid solution

Comment: @user3718334 - we wont do the programming for you. We will help you out if you have any specific programming issues. If that comment above helps you out, please try and update your question with your effort.

Comment: i need just idea i am trying my self if i success i will update