# Curl get request not returning response when response is more than 512 kb

Tags: php, curl

I have encountered a very weird scenario. When I am making a get request via curl through my PHP application to an API and if response is more than 512 kb I am not getting response at all. 
How ever when I am making the same request via my terminal or browser I am getting the response no matter how big response is. I havn't set any max-size limit in my curl request nor it seems like php memory restrictions. Anyone have encountered something like this before? Its a simple curl request by my PHP application. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641073/how-to-set-a-maximum-size-limit-to-php-curl-downloads

Comment: Hi Trralcori,Thank you for your reply. I have already been through the post you suggested. but it did not helped. Actually I have drilled down to the problem and problem is that readfile() function is not able to read file if it is more than 512 kb. Have you encountered something like this before?

Comment: Did you solved the problem? What was the result?

Comment: Ah yeah, please have a look at the second example by "Brian" http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php