# Limit size of file with curl

Tags: php, curl

I use this code to control size of file before download:

```
$info = array();
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // make it a HEAD request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->userAgent());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,$webinfo['ctimeout']); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $webinfo['timeout']); //timeout in seconds 
$head = curl_exec($ch);

$info['type'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$info['size'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
$info['path'] = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$info['filename'] = substr($info['path'], strrpos($info['path'], '/') + 1);
$info['http'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info['url'] = $url;
$info['active'] = false;

if(curl_errno($ch))
  {
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return false;
  }
if($info['http'] == 200)
  {
    $info['active'] = true;
    curl_close($ch);

    if( $info['size'] > 15728640)
      {
        return false;
      }
     return $info;
}
```

So I limit it about 15mb, but I checked my server today and saw it downloaded a file more than 200mb.

What is my wrong on this code?

I think maybe '15728640' is wrong, or should I write it with another format?

Comment: maybe useful or duplicate: [how to set a maximum size limit to php curl downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641073/how-to-set-a-maximum-size-limit-to-php-curl-downloads)