# php file_get_contents downloading too much data

Tags: php, file-get-contents, bandwidth

I notice that when I use file_get_contents I seem to be using more bandwidth than I should.  For example:

```
file_get_contents('https://example.com',false,$ctx,0,99000);
```

Will cause my network RX to jump up about 1.6mb (just using ifconfig and comparing before and after).... I would think it should only jump by 99kb, because I've specified that with the 99000?

Comment: How do you know the RX is isolated to the PHP script and nothing else? Are you running `ifconfig` in the script immediately before and after?

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents is a rather buggy function in PHP.  Consider using curl and following this solution:

[how to set a maximum size limit to php curl downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641073/how-to-set-a-maximum-size-limit-to-php-curl-downloads)

Comment: thanks so much!!  Dr Zizo 's answer worked for me... down to 200kb now instead of 1.6mb