# Can the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION function somehow report back to cancel the cURL request?

Tags: php, http, curl, callback, mime

I'm trying to prevent big PDFs from being downloaded by my cURL bot.

The problematic URLs do not mention ".pdf" anywhere, but they *are* PDFs. The MIME type is: `application/pdf`

I have found a way to extract the MIME type from the request from my `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` callback function. So, if it's a PDF, and over a certain size, I want to abort the request.

But how? How could my callback function which cURL keeps calling while downloading the PDF tell the cURL request to abort?

Is there some sort of "abort signal" I can send? Is that a thing?

I had the "bright idea" to try to `curl_close()` from inside the callback function, but then it just errors out with:

```
curl_close(): Attempt to close cURL handle from a callback
```

What can I do? How do I close the cURL request, or tell it to abort, from within my callback function?

If I have to make a separate HEAD request before the real request each time, that's almost *worse* than all this wasted data traffic. I hope that's not the only solution. It would make me not go through with it at all.

I've looked through the PHP cURL functions but none of them seem to indicate that you can "send an abort signal", and as already shown above, it actively refuses to let me close the cURL handle from the callback function.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17642638/1138321 I think it can help you out.

Comment: @Joey Yes! Thanks! "return 1" was all that was needed. As so many other things, this was undocumented... unless I somehow missed it.